# gcc 4.8.1: combining c code with c++11 code

Tags: c, gcc, c++11

I have not made ​​much effort to discover the cause, but gcc 4.8.1 is giving me a lot of trouble to compile old sources that combine c and c++ plus some new stuff in c++11

I've managed to isolate the problem in this piece of code:

```
# include <argp.h>
# include <algorithm>
```

which compiles fine with `g++ -std=c++0x -c -o test-temp.o test-temp.C` version 4.6.3, ubuntu 12.04

By contrast, with version 4.8.1, the same command line throws a lot of errors:

```
In file included from /home/lrleon/GCC/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/x86intrin.h:30:0,
                 from /home/lrleon/GCC/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/opt_random.h:33,
                 from /home/lrleon/GCC/include/c++/4.8.1/random:51,
                 from /home/lrleon/GCC/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_algo.h:65,
                 from /home/lrleon/GCC/include/c++/4.8.1/algorithm:62,
                 from test-temp.C:4:
/home/lrleon/GCC/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/mmintrin.h: In function ‘__m64 _mm_cvtsi32_si64(int)’:
/home/lrleon/GCC/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/mmintrin.h:61:54: error: can’t convert between vector values of different size
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si (__i, 0);
                                                      ^
```

... and much more.

The same happens if I execute

`g++ -std=c++11 -c -o test-temp.o test-temp.C` ; again, version 4.8.1

But, if I swap the header lines, that is

```
# include <algorithm>
# include <argp.h>
```

then all compiles fine.

Someone enlighten me to understand what is happening?

Comment: Do you use any stl containers in your code?

Comment: Can you provide the output of: `g++ -E -dM -</dev/null | grep 'SSE\|MMX'`

Comment: Hi @Brett. The output is `#define __MMX__ 1
#define __SSE2_MATH__ 1
#define __SSE_MATH__ 1
#define __SSE2__ 1
#define __SSE__ 1`

Comment: @lrleon - It does seem to point to a bug; the template code in `<bits/opt_random.h>` is inside a `#ifdef __SSE3__` block, but the `<x86intrin.h>`, and therefore `<mmintrin.h>`, headers are still included - which lack `#extern "C"` scope as others have pointed out. If your header-order hack works, you might just need to put a note in the code and wait for gcc 4.9 :)

Comment: @lrleon - however, all the intrinsic functions have the `__always_inline__` attribute, so the `extern "C"`shouldn't matter. I think you should risk being 'annoying' by reporting the issue *yet again*, as no action seems to have been taken for a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. As it is really annoying, I hacked it down to `<argp.h>`.

This is the code (in standard gcc header argp.h) which trigger the error on ubuntu 14.04 / gcc 4.8.2:

```
/* This feature is available in gcc versions 2.5 and later.  */
# if __GNUC__ < 2 || (__GNUC__ == 2 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 5) || __STRICT_ANSI__
#  define __attribute__(Spec) /* empty */
# endif
```

This is probably to make headers compatible with old gcc AND to strict ANSI C++ definition. The problem is that --std=c++11 set the `__STRICT_ANSI__` macro.

I've commented the `#define __attribute__(spec)` and the compilation worked fine !

As it is not practical to comment a system header, a workaround is to use `g++ --std=gnu++11` instead of `g++ --std=c++11` as it does not define `__STRICT_ANSI__`. It worked in my case.

It seems to be a bug in gcc.

Comment: I would not call this a bug in GCC. #defining __attribute__ to be empty is a bad idea: GCC uses the __attribute__ mechanism to provide certain extensions (e.g. for vectorization), and by disabling all __attribute__ declarations you are interfering with GCC's internals.

Comment: @Erik: You misunderstood (or I badly explained :-) ). It's the standard gcc header that's redefining __attribute__ as empty. I agree it's a bad thing, and it's why I call it a bug :-) The order of included standard headers should not make a compilation fail !

Comment: @neuro: Okay -- I agree.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug, apparently some headers are missing `extern "C"` declarations at the right places:

> I also just came across this issue with GCC 4.7.2 on Windows. It appears that all the intrin.h headers are missing the extern "C" part. Since the functions are always inline and thus the symbols never show up anywhere this has not been a problem before. But now that another header declares those functions a second time something must be done.

- http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56038

Comment: Thanks for your help @Zeta. I already read the bug report and well, I'll see if I can find a way to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

Two things come to mind:

1) It's a missing `extern "C"` in headers, which is not that rare.

2) Something is wrong with data alignment. Probably you are using STL container to store SSE types, which doesn't guarantee aligment for those. In this case you should implement custom allocator, which will use alligned_malloc. But I think it should've compiled fine in this case, but give you segfault at runtime. But who knows what compilers can detect now :)

Here's something your might want to read on that topic: [About memory alignment](http://www.songho.ca/misc/alignment/dataalign.html) ; [About custom allocators](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement)

p.s. a piece of your code would be nice

Comment: Thanks @Stan for your help. I will study a little more about this issue. I could perfectly give you a piece of my real code. In order that, I would require your coordinates, because it is some big. However, please note that the error can be triggered with only the two lines of code above

Comment: lrleon, if it's only those 2 lines of code, then I'm sure it's missing extern "C" statements in headers as Zeta already said.